# Unable to set parameters for two cameras using Gstreamer-Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set the camera parameters(Exposure and Gain) for two cameras simultaneously using Gstreamer(Python3). I have created two separate pipelines using the camera serial IDs and followed the method used for single (unique)camera pipelines thereafter. However, upon execution of my script, parameters get set only for one of the cameras. Is there anything in the code below that I should amend? TIA.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import time
import sys
import gi

gi.require_version("Tcam", "0.1")
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Tcam, Gst


def main():

    Gst.init(sys.argv)  # init gstreamer

    serial1='05020863'
    serial2='05020864'

    pipeline1 = Gst.parse_launch("tcambin name=source1"
                                " ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx,width=720,height=540,framerate=30/1"
                                " ! tee name=t"
                                " ! queue"
                                " ! videoconvert"
                                " ! ximagesink"
                                " t."
                                " ! queue"
                                " ! videoconvert"
                                " ! avimux"
                                " ! filesink name=fsink1")

    pipeline2 = Gst.parse_launch("tcambin name=source2"
                            " ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx,width=720,height=540,framerate=30/1"
                            " ! tee name=t"
                            " ! queue"
                            " ! videoconvert"
                            " ! ximagesink"
                            " t."
                            " ! queue"
                            " ! videoconvert"
                            " ! avimux"
                            " ! filesink name=fsink2")

    if serial1 is not None:
        camera1 = pipeline1.get_by_name("source1")
        camera1.set_property("serial", serial1)

    if serial2 is not None:
        camera2 = pipeline2.get_by_name("source2")
        camera2.set_property("serial",serial2)

    file_location1 = "/home/pandey/TIS/tiscamera/examples/python/tiscamera-save-stream-1.avi"
    file_location2 = "/home/pandey/TIS/tiscamera/examples/python/tiscamera-save-stream-2.avi"

    camera1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("tcambin")
    camera2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("tcambin")

    camera1.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
    camera1.set_tcam_property("Exposure Auto", False)
    camera1.set_tcam_property("Gain Auto", False)

    camera2.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
    camera2.set_tcam_property("Exposure Auto", False)
    camera2.set_tcam_property("Gain Auto", False)

    camera1.set_tcam_property("Exposure Time",10)
    camera1.set_tcam_property("Gain",450)

    camera2.set_tcam_property("Exposure Time",10)
    camera2.set_tcam_property("Gain",450)


    fsink1 = pipeline1.get_by_name("fsink1")
    
    fsink1.set_property("location", file_location1)

    fsink2 = pipeline2.get_by_name("fsink2")
    
    fsink2.set_property("location", file_location2)


    pipeline1.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    pipeline2.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)




    print("Press Ctrl-C to stop.")

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        pipeline1.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        pipeline2.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
camera1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("tcambin")
camera2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("tcambin")
```

Why are you creating 2 new elements that are completely separate from your pipeline and putting them on ready? You should just use (like you correctly did earlier)

```
camera1 = pipeline1.get_by_name("source1")
camera2 = pipeline1.get_by_name("source2")
```

to get a reference to the actual elements in the pipeline.